# Creating and emptying tile doesn't affect tile preview in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I'm learning to use GeoServer. I'm using its web admin interface. I clicked the tile layer tab, and clicked the empty tab of the layergroup. Based on the GeoServer user manual, this is supposed to remove all saved tiles. But I was still able to see it in preview. I then press the Seed/Truncate tab, and start a new task with "Grid Set" set to "900913", and the rest at default value. I can see tiles is being created from the "List of currently executing tasks". So it seems that tiles were created and tiles were emptied. But the preview works fine in both cases.

Why does it work when there is no tiles?

Comment: what does this have to do with adding tiles to QGIS? It works because that is what GWC does, if there are no tiles it makes them for you

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @IanTurton, thanks for the comment. I've changed the question title... I think I accidentally used a title I previously intended to ask. And I've changed the content. Hopefully it is less like a discussion and more a straight forward question now.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, based on this [Packet video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC5htWx7Szc&t=27s) at 5:27

> When the contact is made to the GeoWebCache endpoint, GeoWebCache will
>   check on the file system to see if that image tile has already been
>   created, and if so that tile will be served back to the browser as a
>   response to the http request. If that tile is not already available,
>   GeoWebCache will dynamically render that tile.

So my guess is after empty, GWC dynamically renders the tile when the request is sent.